# How can the Fermi Level cut the Conduction Band (in a doped Semiconductor)?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

Let’s say we have an intrinsic, undoped semiconductor. The Fermi level will then be in the middle of the band gap between conduction and valence band.
Now let’s introduce n-doping to the system. In the below figure we see that the Fermi level at zero temperature lies between the dopant and conduction level.

[image: Figure 1]
As we increase the temperature the fermi level moves down due to intrinsic charge carriers (from the valence band) which are excited into the conduction band. However, at room temperature the fermi level has moved up in energy in comparison to the undoped case.

Now let’s look at two cases:

1. Weak doping: In this case the fermi level drops fast with increasing temperature. The reason is that the few charge carriers from the donors are readily ‚compensated‘ by an equal amount of charge carriers from the valence band -> The fermi energy is at half the band gap.
2. Strong doping: Also at high temperature the fermi level is near the dopant level. At very high doping it may also be in the middle between the doping and conduction level as it is at zero temperature.

**My question is:**

It is said in nearly every textbook on semiconductor physics that at high doping the fermi level CUTS the conduction band at very high doping (called degenerate doping). Therefore, the semiconductor acts like a metal. But as we have seen from above discussion, the fermi level is, in the best case, in the middle between conduction and dopant level. Is this just one of that things that is often teached in a wrong way or am I understand something wrong?

**Note:** Of course a semiconductor acts like a metal even if the Fermi energy is only very close to the conduction band at high temperature. There are just enough dopants to make the semiconductor conduct.

Comment: I'm not familiar with a textbook that says the Fermi level "cuts" the conduction band in degenerate doping. And I mean Sze, Grove, and Schokley don't say that. And even just below the melting temperature, Si is not particularly conductive relative to a metal, being about 30x less conductive than the (metallic) liquid phase.

Comment: In intrinsic case, the Fermi level is somewhere in the gap, rarely exactly middle unless density of states in valence band equal to that of in conduction band. The doping adds levels to the gap, and the Fermi level can strongly adjust to be near the doping levels. If you have so much doping as to have a curvy band due to the dopants (as opposed to tightly bound flat band), then maybe the books are trying to consider that as the new conduction band?